# Usage of Falcon for Big data processing

Tags: falcon

I wish to process data (for example validate csv column) in `HDFS` using [Falcon](http://falcon.apache.org/). I have succesfully installed Falcon (`version - Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1, Falcon -0.5.0.2.1.1.0`) and able to submit a [job](https://github.com/apache/falcon/blob/master/src/main/examples/entity/filesystem/pig-process.xml). However the job is not running and UI have nothing to start/stop the Job.
I wish to know how to validate the output of a job and proceed to another job depending on validation of first job - a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

you  mentioned that job was submitted.  If you are using the command line of apache falcon, "submit" alone is not enough, "schedule" command should also be run. For falcon "submit" job will not make is go into running state, "schedule" is necessary.

you can refer to http://falcon.apache.org/0.6.1/FalconCLI.html  for all the commands.

Comment: I have ran the submit and schedule command `bin/falcon entity -submitAndSchedule -type process -file examples/entity/filesystem/pig-process.xml` as described in  [installation steps](http://falcon.apache.org/InstallationSteps.html). I can see the job status as running in oozie where as the process status is showing as UNKNOWN in Falcon UI. Whereas please help in answering _validating the output of a job and proceed to another job depending on validation(success/failure) of first job?_

Comment: in feed.xml you can mention availability flag tag. This is the flag / file for which will signify complete availability of feed / data for that instance. For example , process1 produce feed1 as output, and feed1 is input for process2,  you can mention a availability flag in feed1 xml . Process2 will wait till that flag is not present in feed1 produced by process1. Most of the time in hadoop eco system this flag is _SUCCESS, but uses can customise it also.  pls refer to http://falcon.apache.org/0.6.1/EntitySpecification.html#Feed_Specification and search for "Availability Flags"

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a custom logic you can create a oozie workflow and have that workflow submit a falcon job as the last task.

```
<process name="sample-process">
...
   <workflow engine="oozie" path="/projects/bootcamp/workflow"/>
...
</process>
```

https://falcon.apache.org/EntitySpecification.html#Process_Specification

Hope it helps.